# How to linearize a weighted maximum coverage problem?

Tags: linearization, set-covering

Is it possible that the binary variables below be modeled as continuous variables?

\begin{alignat}2\max&\quad\sum _{{e\in E}}w(e_{j})\cdot y_{j}\\\text{s.t.}&\quad\sum {x_{i}}\leq k,\quad&(\text{no more than}\,\,k\,\,\text{sets are selected})\\&\quad{\sum _{e_{j}\in S_{i}}x_{i}\geq y_{j}},\quad&(\text{if}\,\,y_{j}>0\,\,\text{then at least one set}\,\,e_{j}\in S_{i}\,\,\text{is selected})\\&\quad{y_{j}\in \{0,1\}},\quad&(\text{if}\,\,y_{j}=1\,\,\text{then}\,\,e_{j}\,\,\text{is covered})\\&\quad{x_{i}\in \{0,1\}},\quad&(\text{if}\,\,x_{i}=1\,\,\text{then}\,\,S_{i}\,\,\text{is selected for the cover})\end{alignat}

Comment: What is nonlinear here?

Comment: Sorry, actually the correct question should be:
Is it possible that the binary variables above be modeled as continuous variables?

Comment: Hi and welcome to ORSE. Could you please edit your question based on the comment that you posted?

Comment: The max covering problem is well known to be NP hard, meaning a linear formulation would require an exponential number of variables/constraints

Comment: @OguzToragay sure!

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no continuous form of the maximal covering location problem (MCLP) with a guarantee of providing the same optimal solution as the integer program. However, in addition to the formulation OP presented, [Church & ReVelle (1974)](https://rsaiconnect.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1435-5597.1974.tb00902.x)<sup>1</sup>
 proposed a second formulation for the problem in their breakthrough paper, that is as follows:

\begin{alignat}4 
\min &\quad z = \sum_{{j\in J}}w_j\cdot \bar y_{j}\\\text{s.t.}&\quad 
\sum_{i \in N_j} {x_{i}} + \bar y_{j} \geq 1, \qquad \forall j \in J;\tag1\\&\quad 
\sum_{i \in I} x_{i} = k; \tag2\\&\quad 
{x_{i} \in \{0,1\}}, \qquad \forall i \in I;\tag3\\&\quad
{\bar y_{j} \in \{0,1\}}, \qquad \forall j \in J. \tag4\end{alignat}

and stated that this problem can be solved with continuous variables where both $x_{i}$ and $\bar y_{j}$ are defined as non-negative. That way, in 80% of the cases the optimal solution of the linear program was equal to the zero-one solution in their computations.

P.S. In this formulation $N_j = \{i \in I | d_{ij} \leq S\}$, and $\bar y_j = 1 - y_j$

<sub>References:</sub>

<sub>[1] Church, Richard, and Charles ReVelle. "The maximal covering location problem." Papers of the regional science association. Vol. 32. No. 1. Springer-Verlag, 1974.</sub>

Comment: That's great. I'll test that and see if I can get close to 80%. Thank you.